# Appengine (python flavour) request source port

Tags: python, google-app-engine, request, port

With AppEngine, the IP of request can be retrieve in Python by :

```
the_request_handler.request.environ["REMOTE_ADDR"]
```

Do you know if it's possible to get the source port number and how to proceed?

Comment: Why would you need the source port number?

Comment: What do you plan to do with the remote port?  You already have a socket connection to use for communications; and the remote port is almost certain to be ephemeral.  It would only seem to be useful if you're attempting to do some sort of "port knocking" access control; an that only if the remote/client can be relied upon to open the connection using a specific source port.

Comment: It would be long to explain, but we need to identify the HTTP client without the help of a cookie. An ip/port pair would do the trick during the lasting of a session.

Comment: The source port is not guaranteed to remain the same across a session. In the worst case, every single request from the same user could come from a different port, and it's practically certain that a user will be making requests from at least 2 ports simultaneously.

Comment: Yes Nick but the client is not a browser (sorry for the misunderstanding), it's an ad-hoc client that use HTTP, but doesn't support the full 2616/2965 RFC. It initiates itself on a random but fix port, and, in this case, its retrieving from the server side is relevant.
If the source port definitively can't be retreive from the server (wich seems strange to me) we could send it within the request (but port translation could be a concern) or we will have to develop some kind of cookie-like support (that I hoped to avoid)...

Answer (score 0):

should be available via

```
the_request_handler.request.environ["REMOTE_PORT"]
```